# What is the proper API calling Syntax from Alamofire?

Tags: alamofire, httpie

I am trying to call following API:

```
http -v -a qi.test.ac@gmail.com:pasword -f POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/messages' from="qi.test.ac@gmail.com" to={"qi.test.ac@gmail.com","qi_test_ac@yahoo.com"}  subject="test_sub"  bodyText="testing hello"
```

I successfully called it from terminal using [HTTPie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) using normally above command.

Now I want to call it from [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). I have tried in following way:

```
    parameters = [

        "from" : fromMail,
        "to" : ["qi.test.ac@gmail.com","qi_test_ac@yahoo.com"]
    ]
    parameters["subject"] = message.getSubject()
    parameters["bodyText"] = message.getBodyText()

    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parameters)//, encoding: .JSON)
        .authenticate(user: userName, password: password)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<201)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseJSON {

            (_, _, jsonData, error) in

            if(error != nil) {

                println("\n sendMessage attempt json response:")
                println(error!)
                delegate?.messageSent?(false)
                return
            }
            println("Server response during message sending:\n")
            let swiftyJSONData = JSON(jsonData!)
            println(swiftyJSONData)
            delegate?.messageSent?(true)
    }
```

I have tried by url encoding which is by default and also in json encoding. But not succeeded yet. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have figured out that, [httpie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) sends array elements as `to=a@gmail.com&to=b@gmail.com`. But [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) sends this as `to[]=a@gmail.com&to[]=b@gmail.com`. Once I removed this [] from Alamofire server is now able to read params. Is it a good solution? Our api server is using a modified version of Dropwizard.

Comment: If you need to send them that way, then I'd suggest you try out the `ParameterEncoding.Custom` option. That will make it much easier. I'd suggest reading through the public [docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L48-L66) for each of the encoding types as well as the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#parameter-encoding).