# How to add multiple same-name query parameters in Angular $http

Tags: angularjs, http, url

All

What I want to do is Adding multiple parameters with same name to request URL with AngularJS $http, making the URL sent like  http://localhost:8080/?value=1&value=2.....

This post also described the similar situation:
[Sending HTTP request with multiple parameters having same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835074/sending-http-request-with-multiple-parameters-having-same-name)

Could any one help with in AngularJS $http?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried passing an array?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use an array like this:

```
 var params = {};
 params.someParmName = ['value1', 'value2'];
```

This will send value1 and value2 with the same querystring key 'someParmName'.

Here is an example GET request:

```
 var parameters = {};
 parameters.someParmName = ['value1', 'value2'];

 $http({
    url: 'api_url', 
    method: "GET",
    params: parameters
});
```

Comment: I had a code error I just fixed, fyi.  If you are copying look my answer over.

Comment: FYI: $http returns a promise.

Comment: As per your answer it will be someParmName=value1&someParmName=value2 but can it be changed to make query like someParmName=value1,value2 ?

Answer (score 4):

You call also use [URLSearchParams](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html) for the parameters. For example:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();

params.append('someParmName', 'value1');
params.append('someParmName', 'value2');

// the following statement will form this url: ?someParmName=value1&someParmName=value2
http.get(api_url, {search: params});
```

Or

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();

params.set('someParmName', ['value1', 'value2'];);

// the following statement will form this url: ?someParmName=value1,value2
http.get(api_url, {search: params});
```