# Add multiple parameters with same name in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, http-get, angular11

What I want to do is adding multiple parameters with same name to request URL with Angular 11:

```
http://example.com/somepath?data=1&data=2&data=3
```

[I've seen this post, but accepted answer is not eligible to me because it is Angular 1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115354/how-to-add-multiple-same-name-query-parameters-in-angular-http/28115881)

What I've tried is:

```
private getParams(value: string): HttpParams {
    const values = value.split("/");    

    const httpParams = new HttpParams();    

    values.forEach((item) => httpParams.set('value', item));    
    return httpParams;
}
```

and then I try to send it:

```
public getConfig(view: string): Observable<IFooBar[]> {
    const params = this.getParams(view);
    return this.http.get<IFooBar[]>(`$somePerson/someMethod`, { params });  
}
```

But what url becomes is without params:

http://localhost:8000/api/somePerson/someMethod

How to send parameters with the same name?

Comment: why don't just _localhost:8000/api/somePerson/someMethod?values=1,2,3,4_

Comment: Maybe it's because you are calling `getParamsView` to get params, when the functions is named `getParams`? At least, it is according to what you have posted.

Comment: @R.Richards sorry, it is typo. I’ve updated answer

Comment: @Nick I do not know. Is it best practise ti send parameters like you asked?

Comment: @Learner if you just want multiple values for a single parameter i would suggest to go for that and in your route handler split them with .split(',') and that's it, you have now an array of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is set and append returns a new instance so make sure you keep it updated. Based on [doc](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams).

```
let params = new HttpParams().append('value', '1');
params = params.append('value', '2');
params = params.append('value', '3');
params = params.append('value', '4');

console.log(params.getAll('value'));
```

So you should write something like this:

```
private getParams(value: string): HttpParams {
  const values:string[] = value.split("/");    

  let httpParams:HttpParams = new HttpParams();    

  values.forEach((item) => {
    httpParams = httpParams.append('value', item)
  });    

  return httpParams;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case i would probably pass more values on the same parameter like this:

```js
public getConfig(view: string): Observable<IFooBar[]> {
    const params = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    return this.http.get<IFooBar[]>('somePerson/someMethod', { params: { values: params.join(',') } });  
}
```

And in your server endpoint(posting an example with express):

```
app.get('somePerson/someMethod', (req, res) => {
    const values = req.query.values?.split(',');
    /* Now you have your values as an array of values */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do like this:

```
      constructor(private filtersService: FiltersService,
                  private router: Router,
                  ) {
      }   

     private addMuiltipleParams() {
        router.navigate([], {
              queryParams: {
                paramName: ['value1', 'value2'],
              }
            });

}
```